# Javascript multiple alerts

Tags: javascript, debugging, events, alert, clipboard

I have a very limited knowledge of Javascript, I recently started working on a project where some JS is involved. I had an issue where multiple `alert`s appeared. The original code was:

```
  clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    alert('Link successfully copied.');
    e.clearSelection();
  });
```

Reversing the two lines (I suspected that `clearSelection` fired another event) solved the issue.

```
  clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    e.clearSelection();
    alert('Link successfully copied.');
  });
```

Why did this actually work ?

**Edit.**

The clipboard comes from the library [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/) and is defined here:

```
var clipboard = new Clipboard(".btnToDoSthg");
```

Comment: what kind of object `clipboard` is ? please disclose the `clearSelection()` too.

Comment: does a clearSelection fire a success event as well? Maybe you could check the `e` argument to see why the success event was thrown

Comment: i suspect that its not that e.clearSelection() triggers new event but the opposite, calling before alert will prevent multiple alerts. can you remove e.clearSelection() at all and see if you get multiple alerts?